# HTML5 and CSS with mobile app development - Cross platform layouts

Tags: android, ios, html, css, cordova

Iv been using phonegap for sometime, and I was wondering what you do with regard to cross platform development. Now this is great for "cross platform" but I think the CSS layouts is the trick here..

What im referring to here is layouts. With iPhone its easy, there are two possible sizes so thats no biggy.

I was wondering how you do your css for Android and Ios? I mean Android has so much devices each with their own sizes.

I use % widths and heights and that works well I guess, but sometimes you have to have specific heights with lets say n iScroll element or something. How do you design your CSS or Javascript for this?

Answer (score 0):

for iScroll you can specify `min-height`. if content exeeds the minimum height it adjusts the height according to content length.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not what the question was about